# Can I change the IP address of a virtual machine with vmware package?

Tags: java, vmware

I created virtual machine on ESX (on vSphere Client) by vmware package:
[Look here](http://www.doublecloud.org/2010/04/how-to-import-and-export-ovf-packages/) 
.
 but I can not set the IP address from the code.

I tried:

```
ServiceInstance si = new ServiceInstance(new URL(Url), user, password, true);
  VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine) new InventoryNavigator(si.getRootFolder()).searchManagedEntity("VirtualMachine", "NewVmName");
  System.out.println( vm.getGuest().toolsRunningStatus);
  vm.getGuest().setIpAddress(ipAddress);
```

But it didn't change. Does anyone know what can be done to update IP Address?

Answer (score 1):

The IP Address of a Virtual Machine is controlled by the Virtual Machine itself. If you do want to set the IP Address of the Virtual Machine, change the network adapter to "Bridged" and set the IP Address in the Virtual Machine itself. Refer to: [Setting IP Address on Windows](https://superuser.com/a/186445/767073), [Linux](https://superuser.com/a/1216519/767073),  [and Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/01/set-ip-address-from-the-mac-command-line/).
Sources: Superuser, OSXDaily

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do this.

One way is to use the [CustomizeVM_Task command](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/converter-sdk/conv61_apireference/vim.VirtualMachine.html#customize) and give it a customization spec that changes the IP. The VM will need to be powered off when you do it, and when you turn it on after customization it will boot, change the IP, and then boot again. See examples [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/vijava/discussion/826592/thread/5d6ff04c/) and [here](http://www.vcoportal.de/2011/04/customize-a-virtual-machine/).

Another way is to leverage the [ProcessManager](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#/doc/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.html) of the `GuestOperationsManager` to launch a command which changes the IP (the exact command will depend on the guest OS). This will not require a reboot but note that you will need to provide valid credentials for the guest.

If you're open to using PowerCLI then you can use `Invoke-VMScript`. See e.g. [this example](http://notesofascripter.com/2016/04/05/using-powercli-set-ip-update-vmware-tools/).