# Assign static ip to vm in vmware using java

Tags: java, ip, virtual-machine, clone, vmware

I want to assign static IP address to the VM in the vmware while cloning/creating VM using java. How can i achive this. Please share me code snippet if anybody knows it.

Comment: There's a duplicate question asked. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579403/assign-static-ip-to-vm-in-vmware-using-java

Comment: @BastiaanvanHaastrecht I believe you meant to post a different link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023226/can-i-change-the-ip-address-of-a-virtual-machine-with-vmware-package

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is straightforward, either in Java or any other technology. When cloning a VMWare VM the network identity remains the same, apart from the MAC address. How an IP is allocated is a matter for the guest OS to determine, using methods that the OS normally uses. If you have configured the guest OS to use a static IP, then the clone will also have the same static IP.

VMWare does provide tools that allow access to the virtual disks of guest VMs; how these work varies from (host) platform to platform. So you could, in principle, set a static IP by manipulating the network configuration of the guest OS at the file level. With a Linux guest you might, for example, programatically modify `/etc/sysconfig/network`. A process like this would be particularly painful for a Windows guest, I think, because the network configuration will be in some opaque format, and not easily modified by a program.

It looks like a horrible job, bordering on impossible. However, I would be happy to be proven wrong about this, as I clone VMs all the time. Normally I just set the guest OS to use DHCP then, if I care about the IP number, I have the DHCP server provide a specific one when the guest boots.